# Create a query to retrieve data from a comboBox

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I have stored values from my SQL database into a combo box on my windows form (locations). Now what I'd like to do, is create a query which will retrieve any bookings that match the users input.

So far I have got it working so that it searches for bookings between two dates the user enters.  Now what I would like to do is include the locations within the query. This is where I'm having some issues.

As I've stored the location values from the database inside of the comboBox, "comboBox1.text" or "comboBox1.item" doesn't work. I'm currently using comboBox1.ValueMember but that doesn't seem to work either.

```
public void displayDataInGrid()
{
    try
    {
         string query = (" SELECT * FROM coachSchedule WHERE dateOfDeparture BETWEEN ' " + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + " ' AND ' " + dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + " ' AND stationDeparture=' "+comboBox1.SelectedValue+" ' AND stationArrival ' "+comboBox2.SelectedValue+" ' "); 
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        connection.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection);
        adapter.Fill(dt);
        datagridview1.DataSource = dt;
        connection.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception message)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(message.Message);
    }
```

EDIT, this is how i have populated the data within the comboBox:

```
public void displayDataInComboBox(string query, string columnName, ComboBox comboBox)
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
            SqlDataReader reader;
            reader = sc.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add(columnName, typeof(string));
            dt.Load(reader);
            comboBox.ValueMember = columnName;
            comboBox.DataSource = dt;
            connection.Close();
        }
```

Comment: First priority: use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting errors.

Comment: `ValueMember` isn't data.  It's just a reference to the property or column used in the data.  Look at `SelectedValue`.

Comment: i changed it to comboBox1.SelectedValue and it doesn't work. The issue is definitely with the comboBox as I've taken that code away from the query and it retrieves the data fine using just the dates. Can you think of anything else that it may be?

Comment: Your posted code still shows `ValueMember` so I can't see what you changed.  How did you populate the ComboBox?  We don't see that code either.

Comment: apologies, I've now made the edits :- )

Comment: In `displayDataInGrid()`, but a debug break on the line `DataTable dt = new DataTable();` and inspect what your `query` string says when the line gets hit when you run the code.

Comment: You have a space before the `SelectedValue` and after it so you are doing a text search on a value that almost certainly doesn't exit. Just remove the superfluous spaces.

Comment: ive edited the query and removed the spaces, it returns nothing :/

Comment: Your spaces are still there.  This line: `AND stationArrival ' "+comboBox2.SelectedValue+" ' "` is missing an equal sign and if you notice, you have extra spaces as noted.  If there was a value of AAA, it would read `AND stationArrival ' AAA '`  Using parameters would have avoided that.

Comment: im an idiot lol. Its working. Thanks guys!

Comment: If you missed it because of the empty Try-Catch, there is a reason why empty Try-Catch blocks are bad.

Comment: @Sock12, I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can make a reply and click '✔' to mark your reply as an answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.